# Eliminate ElasticSearch results which are close/similar matching

Tags: elasticsearch

When I search for "baby oil" , my Index returns lot of similar results (NOT SAME) like shown below. Just few extra characters like , # or smiley etc ...

Even though the field-rawtext that I'm indexing is "TEXT" , I have created a Keyword field in field-rawtext , hoping that I can use COLLAPSE feature.

But collapse feature is not working.

1. Is there anything I can do in the QUERY Part ?
2. Is there anything I can do during indexing ?

Thanks.

```
**CREATE INDEX**


PUT /index_name
{
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "number_of_shards": 20,  
      "number_of_replicas": 0 
    }
  },
  "mappings" : {
      "properties" : {
        "rawtext" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 1024
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
}

**READ_FROM_INDEX**

GET INDEX_NAME/_search
{
  "size": 100, 
  "_source": ["rawtext"],
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "default_field": "rawtext",
      "query": "baby oil"
    }
  },
  "collapse": {
    "field": "rawtext.keyword"
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Why don't you use match query with operator AND?

Comment: {"size":100,"_source":["rawtext"],"query":{"bool":{"must":[{"match":{"rawtext":"baby"}},{"match":{"rawtext":"oil"}}]}},"collapse":{"field":"rawtext.keyword"}} @rabbitbr no impact ..

Comment: Do you only want products with the exact text "baby oil"? The texts "?baby oil?" or "Baby oil?" should they be ignored?